# Mapping twitter style followers following relationship in EF Code First with extra data in the join table

Tags: entity-framework, ef-code-first, many-to-many

My question is almost the exact same as the question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13648977/mapping-twitter-style-followers-following-relationship-in-ef-code-first) but with a slight twist.

In entity framework code first how would one create a many to many relationship (such as a twitter style user has users who follow them and in turn the same user can follow a list of users) but also store an extra column (e.g. FollowedDate) on the join table?

I imagine the resulting tables would look something like below but I'm not sure of how the code first model would fit together.

```
user
------------------
|  id | Username |
------------------

join table
--------------------------------------------------------
| followerUserId | followingUserId | followedTimestamp |
--------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: Unfortunately I'm not sure you can do that in a straightforward way (but you can work around it): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7404573/how-to-add-a-column-to-a-link-table-with-code-first, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7289160/ef-code-first-additional-column-in-join-table-for-ordering-purposes